# Looking for an old anime about men who transform into winged sort of machines

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've seen this for the first time 13 years ago. I don't exactly remember much of the show except the dragged out transformation sequences and the girl who helped these men hide their identities. I remember her always delivering clothes to them as they somehow always end up naked after a transformation.

Comment: If you remember anything else, what happens, what the characters looks like, etc. You can [edit] your post to include that.

Comment: We also have a guide at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 that will be very helpful for improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Chouja Reideen](https://anilist.co/anime/2127/Chouja-Raideen)*

> Hishou, Ginga, Ace, Hayate, and Ikazuchi all work at a studio doing various idol-related jobs at the request of their manager, Reiko. But in reality, these five teenagers are really the Reideens, a group of superheroes who fight the Super Devils sent by Lushu, a mysterious being.

[image: Image showing some of the characters without clothing after their transformation ends]

Comment: Oh wow that was quick... thank you, this is the anime!